# Matlab algorithm to transform coordinates

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of size `MxNxK`. Suppose I transform `A` in a column vector `B`. I want a code that, given the coordinates of the `i,j,h`th element in `A`, splits the coordinate `k` of the same element in `B`.

I have written a code that does what I want. As I'm trying to optimise my code as much as I can (the change of coordinate operation should be repated millions of times), I would like to know whether you can think of more efficient solutions.

Let me explain better with an example.

```
clear all

A(:,:,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A(:,:,2)=[7 8 9; 10 11 12];
A(:,:,3)=[13 14 15; 16 17 18];
A(:,:,4)=[19 20 21; 22 23 24];

B=reshape(A,[24,1]);
```

Suppose `changecoord(i,j,h)` is the function that gives the position of
`A(i,j,h)` in `B`

Then, this algorithm should split

```
%changecoord(1,1,1)=1
%changecoord(2,1,1)=2
%changecoord(1,2,1)=3
%changecoord(2,2,1)=4
%changecoord(1,3,1)=5
%changecoord(2,3,1)=6

%changecoord(1,1,2)=7
%changecoord(2,1,2)=8
%changecoord(1,2,2)=9
%changecoord(2,2,2)=10
%changecoord(1,3,2)=11
%changecoord(2,3,2)=12

%changecoord(1,1,3)=13
%changecoord(2,1,3)=14
%changecoord(1,2,3)=15
%changecoord(2,2,3)=16
%changecoord(1,3,3)=17
%changecoord(2,3,3)=18

%changecoord(1,1,4)=19
%changecoord(2,1,4)=20
%changecoord(1,2,4)=21
%changecoord(2,2,4)=22
%changecoord(1,3,4)=23
%changecoord(2,3,4)=24
```

This is the algorithm that I wrote

```
function k=changecoord(s1, s2,i,j,h)
%s1=size(A,1)
%s2=size(A,2)
p1=(s1*s2)*h-(s1*s2)+1:1:s1*s2*h;
p2=p1(s2*j-s2+1:s2*j);
k=p2(i);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function will not be efficient, because it creates a (potentially) large array, then finds one value in it:

```
function k=changecoord(s1, s2,i,j,h)
%s1=size(A,1)
%s2=size(A,2)
p1=(s1*s2)*h-(s1*s2)+1:1:s1*s2*h;
p2=p1(s2*j-s2+1:s2*j);
k=p2(i);
end
```

You can see that if `j` and `h` are 1, then `k==i`. This is valid for all `i` values, which range `1:s1`. The next element in memory has `i=1` again, but `j=2`. Here, `k=s1+1`. That is, `k=s1+i` for all elements where `j=2`. When `j=3` this becomes `k=2*s1+i`, etc. Thus in 2D indexing:

```
k = i + (j-1)*s1;
```

We can do exactly the same for the next index. When `i=s1` and `j=s2`, we have exhausted the first plane, and start finding elements in the second plane (`h=2`). `k` will thus be increased by `s1*s2` to access all the elements in this plane. Thus:

```
k = i + (j-1)*s1 + (h-1)*s1*s2;
```

which can be simplified a bit by

```
k = i + ( j-1 + (h-1)*s2 ) * s1;
```

This same computation is performed by [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), though that function has a little bit more overhead than writing out the computation by hand.