# Coordinates after reshaping 4d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of size `MxNxKxP`. Suppose I transform `A` in a column vector `B` using `reshape`. I want a code that, given the coordinates of the `(i,j,h,p)`th element in `A`, gives me the coordinate `k` of the same element in `B`. Could you help me to do that?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619129/matlab-algorithm-to-transform-coordinates) code does it for 3d matrices but I don't know how to generalise it to 4d.

Let me explain better with an example.

```
clear all

A(:,:,1,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A(:,:,2,1)=[7 8 9; 10 11 12];
A(:,:,1,2)=[13 14 15; 16 17 18];
A(:,:,2,2)=[19 20 21; 22 23 24];

B=reshape(A,[2*3*2*2,1]);
```

Suppose `changecoord(i,j,h,p)` is the function that gives the position of
`A(i,j,h,p)` in `B`

Then, this algorithm should split

```
%changecoord(1,1,1,1)=1
%changecoord(2,1,1,1)=2
%changecoord(1,1,2,2)=19
%changecoord(1,2,2,2)=21 
%etc.
```

Comment: [sub2ind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reshaping, elements of the array don't change order in memory. Thus, the [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1301) stays the same. You can obtain the linear index from your `(i,j,h,p)` coordinates using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) (as [rahnema1 suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069859/coordinates-after-reshaping-4d-matrix-in-matlab#comment93038260_53069859)).

```
index = sub2ind(size(A),i,j,h,p);
```

Now, for any `B` obtained by reshaping `A`,

```
A(index) == B(index)
```

You can retrieve the coordinates in `B` using [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
B = reshape(A,4,3,2);
[i,j,h] = ind2sub(size(B),index);
```